# Swift Array Type

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, generics

I think I should be more clear, here are my classes:

```
    import Foundation
    import Alamofire

    public class BaseService<T>  : ServiceRequest {

        public var requestType: Alamofire.Method = .GET
        public var path: String = "/"

        var requireLogin:Bool = false

        var consumer:RequestInformer?


        public func requestSuccess<T>(request: Request, response: T) {
            consumer?.requestSuccess(request, response: response)

        }

        public func requestFailed(request: Request, error: NSError) {
            consumer?.requestFailed(request, error: error)
        }
    }

    extension BaseService where T:Sortable {

        func start() {
            if requireLogin {

            }
//problem is here, T is [CampaignModel] but I need CampaignModel class, not array.            NetworkManager.sharedInstance.sendRequest(self,ResponseListModel<T>.self)
        }
    }



    extension BaseService where T:NSObject {

        func start() {
            if requireLogin {

            }
            NetworkManager.sharedInstance.sendRequest(self,ResponseModel<T>.self)
        }
    }
```

Then I want to use BaseService like below:

```
import Alamofire

public class ListCampaignService : BaseService<[CampaignModel]> {

    override init() {
        super.init()
        path = "/xxx/yyy.json"
        requestType = .GET
    }
}
```

That means ListCampaignService returns CampaignModel array. Bu I have to handle object return type rather than array, something like below

```
import Alamofire

public class SomeOtherService : BaseService<SomeClass> {

    override init() {
        super.init()
        path = "/aaa/bbb.json"
        requestType = .GET
    }
}
```

Comment: what are you going to do with the type once you have it ?

Comment: will use it for json to object mapping

Comment: I think you've lost the question in your "clarification"...

Answer (score 3):

Try this as a start:

```
func getType<T>(array:[T]) -> T.Type {
    return T.self
}

getType(["1", "2", "3"]) // String.Type
getType([1, 2, 3]) // Int.Type
getType([1, "2", 3.0]) // NSObject.Type
getType([[1], [2], [3]]) // Array<Int>.Type
getType([]) // compile time error "Generic parameter 'T' could not be inferred"
```

Comment: You should probably replace `Any` with `T.Type`

Comment: One doesn't *need* to - I guess it depends what he wants to do with it afterwards!

Comment: True, that's why I said "should probably", not "need" ;) Although I would always go with the most descriptive type available – and `T.Type` is a lot more descriptive than `Any`.

Comment: Agreed. Changed the answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying to get all the objects of a particular type from a generic `Array` you could extend `Array` like this:

```
extension Array {
    func itemsOfType<T>() -> [T] {
        return self.flatMap { $0 as? T }
    }
}

let x = [1, 2, 3, "foo", "bar", NSDate()]

let ints : [Int] = x.itemsOfType()      // [1, 2, 3]
let altInts = x.itemsOfType() as [Int]  // [1, 2, 3]
let str : [String] = x.itemsOfType()    // ["foo", "bar"]
let dates : [NSDate] = x.itemsOfType()  // ["May 17, 2016, 6:23 AM"]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use generics in your function, it's really simple:

```
func test<T>(array: [T]) {
    // array elements are of type T
    print(T.self) 
}
```

If you don't use generics (outside functions) then you can do this:

```
let array = [1, 2, 3]
let type = array.dynamicType.Element.self
print(type)     // Int.Type
```

If you're coming from the future: Swift 3.0 will use `Self` instead of `dynamicType`